# C# Convert back from thousand separator to int

Tags: c#

I have a code that makes an int to a thousend separator but when I try to save this value in the text box to the database I want to remove the space between. I could not do this with replace(" ","").

```
YearTB.Text = (String.Format(culture, "{0:n0}", Int32.Parse(YearTB.Text)));
```

What is in the box is for example "536 396" but the space between is not an " ". its the effect of the thousand seperator. How can I return it back to int. "536396".

Comment: This has to be responsability of the control to convert it into numeric type, it knows all required information to perform such convertion.

Comment: What is the exact value you want to convert?

Comment: If this is a format of a known culture, parse the string using that culture and then write it using a culture that matches the format the database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to convert to a string without the thousands rather than to an int:

```
string result = text.Replace(culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator, "");
```

This assumes that `culture` is the `CultureInfo` with which the number was formatted using a thousand separator.

Alternatively if you want to convert to an int, you can use `int.Parse()` directly and specify that you want to allow the thousands separator (which I think is a better approach):

```
int result = int.Parse(text, NumberStyles.AllowThousands, culture);
```

Comment: int result = int.Parse(text, NumberStyles.AllowThousands); was enough.
One problem that my  GridViewChargeTime.UpdateRow(r.RowIndex, false); could not save to the database because the textboxes still have the thousand format.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string str = "536 396";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "");
```